Two's complement multiplication decomposition
From the book "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective" :

We know that $$ x \cdot y $$ can be written as a 2w-bit two's-complement number. Let  $$u$$ denote the unsigned number represented by the lower  w bits, and $$v$$ denote the two's-complement number represented by the upper w bits. Then, based on Equation 2.3, we can see that $$x \cdot y = v \cdot 2^w + u$$
Equation 2.3:
$$B2T_w(\vec{x}) \overset{\text{def}}{=} -x_{w-1} \cdot 2^{w-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{w-2} x_i \cdot 2^i \quad$$

I understand why $$x \cdot y = v \cdot 2^w + u$$
But struggling to understand how $$v \cdot 2^w + u$$ can be based on 2.3

Let the binary form of $x \cdot y$ be represented using $\vec{a}$ whose dimension is $2w$.
Therefore, by Equation 2.3
$$ \begin{aligned}
x \cdot y = B2T_w(\vec{a}) &\overset{\text{def}}{=} -a_{2w-1} \cdot 2^{2w-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{2w-2} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad  
 \\ &= -a_{2w-1} \cdot 2^{2w-1} + \sum_{i=w}^{2w-2} a_i \cdot 2^i + \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad
 \\ &= (-a_{2w-1} \cdot 2^{2w-1} + \sum_{i=w}^{2w-2} a_i \cdot 2^i) + \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad
 \\ &= (-a_{w+w-1} \cdot 2^{w + w-1} + \sum_{i=w}^{w +w-2} a_i \cdot 2^i) + \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad
 \\ &= (-a_{w+w-1} \cdot 2^{w + w-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{w-2} a_{w+i} \cdot 2^{w+i}) + \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad
 \\ &= (-a_{w+w-1} \cdot 2^{w-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{w-2} a_{w+i} \cdot 2^{i}) \cdot 2^w + \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} a_i \cdot 2^i \quad
\\ &= v \cdot 2^w + u
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that the above equations has nothing to do with the fact that it is a result of product between two $w$-bit number. It rather concerns with how a signed $2w$-bit number can be decomposed into $w$ bit signed and unsigned values.
